# How to loop through children in MXML View?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, mxml, flex-spark

I have mxml component and want to go through all its children, that I've created in it and not to go deeper. For example I have this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:chat="org.mirapolis.virtualroom.chat.*"
         height="100%" width="100%" 
         initialize="init()" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[                   
            import org.mirapolis.virtualroom.chat.ChatModule;

            private function init() : void{
                setDisplayStrategy(this);
            }
            private function setDisplayStrategy(element :  UIComponent) : void{
                for(var i : int = 0; i < element.numChildren; i++){
                    var child : UIComponent = element.getChildAt(i) as UIComponent;
                    if (child != null && child.descriptor != null){
                        trace(child);
                        setDisplayStrategy(child);
                    }
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Form>
            <mx:FormItem label="email">
                <s:TextInput id="email" />
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem>
                <s:Button
                    label="submit" />
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
    </mx:VBox>
    <chat:ChatView id="id1" />
    <chat:ChatView id="id2" />
</mx:VBox>
```

And trace will give me this

```
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem10
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem10.email
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem16
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem16.Button17
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2
```

which is exactly what I need. But if I add any spark element to my view, `child.descriptor` will give `null` and the whole thing will break up. Without `child.descriptor` check this code will go deeper in all components which is absolutely not needed.

So my question is - is it possible to get all children that have been added to mxml view?

**UPD:**
Now it works better:

```
public static function setDisplayStrategy(element : UIComponent) : void{
            trace(element);
            if (element is IVisualElementContainer){
                for(var i : int = 0; i < (element as IVisualElementContainer).numElements; i++){
                    var child : UIComponent = (element as IVisualElementContainer).getElementAt(i) as UIComponent;
                    if (child){
                        setDisplayStrategy(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But still takes too many deeps:

```
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem10
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem10.email
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem16
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.VBox8.Form9.FormItem16.Button17
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1.chatWrapper
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1.chatWrapper.ScrollerSkin28.Group24
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1.chatWrapper.ScrollerSkin28.Group24.chatArea
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1.userMessage
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id1.send
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2.chatWrapper
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2.chatWrapper.ScrollerSkin105.Group101
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2.chatWrapper.ScrollerSkin105.Group101.chatArea
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2.userMessage
videoconference.ApplicationSkin2._ApplicationSkin_Group1.contentGroup.MainView7.id2.send
```

Is it possible to stop on MainView7.id1 and MainView7.id2 in my example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to loop over the numElement property.

However, I suggest you read this excellent post [here](http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/?p=296)

Comment: Thank you! numElements helped me to avoid most of elements that I don't need, but my main problem is to see all elements in current mxml (see my update).